# Decision Tree Modelling

Tags: r, modeling, predictive-models, cart

Can anyone explain me about Decision tree parameters - minSplit, minBucket, Complexity, minDepth with some simple decision tree example?

And how this parameters will affect the accuracy measure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good introduction to building decision trees with the rpart package in R. Although it's not cart, it provides very good insights on how this works.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf